# ¿Como obtener la cantidad de sabados y domingos que hay en un rango de fechas en mysql?

Tags: mysql

Quiero obtener la cantidad de sabados y domingos en un rango de fechas, estoy intentando con la siguiente solución pero no me contabiliza correctamente los días domingo.

```
set @domingo=7;
set @sabado=6;

select
         cr.edit_date
        , case when dayofweek(cr.edit_date)-1=0 then 7 else dayofweek(cr.edit_date)-1 end as minimo
        , case when dayofweek(date_add(cr.edit_date, interval cr.of_days_in_uw_sub day))-1=0 then 7 else dayofweek(date_add(cr.edit_date, interval cr.of_days_in_uw_sub day))-1 end as max
        , date_add(cr.edit_date, interval cr.of_days_in_uw_sub day) as close_date
        , datediff(date_add(cr.edit_date, interval cr.of_days_in_uw_sub day),cr.edit_date) DIV 7 + (CASE WHEN (case when dayofweek(cr.edit_date)-1=0 then 7 else dayofweek(cr.edit_date)-1 end)=@domingo then 1 else 0 end ) as 'Domingos'
        , datediff(date_add(cr.edit_date, interval cr.of_days_in_uw_sub day),cr.edit_date) DIV 6 + (CASE WHEN (case when dayofweek(cr.edit_date)-1=0 then 7 else dayofweek(cr.edit_date)-1 end)=@sabado then 1 else 0 end ) as 'Sabados'
       

from mi_tabla as cr
where edit_date between '2021-05-10' and '2021-05-16';
```

Mi tabla esta de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ejemplo: de 2121-05-12 al 2021-05-25  hay dos domingos y dos sabados, pero solo me contabiliza un domingo.

Answer (score 0):

Te propongo algo así:

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN DAYOFWEEK(edit_date)=7 THEN 'Sábado'
    WHEN DAYOFWEEK(edit_date)=1 THEN 'Domingo'
  END dia,COUNT(*) repeticiones
  FROM fechas
  WHERE edit_date BETWEEN '2021-05-10' and '2021-05-16'
  AND DAYOFWEEK(edit_date) IN (1,7)
  GROUP BY DAYOFWEEK(edit_date);
```

Para este dataset:

```
CREATE TABLE fechas(
  id_fecha int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  edit_date date
  );

INSERT INTO fechas (edit_date) VALUES
  ('2021-05-11'),
  ('2021-05-11'),
  ('2021-05-14'),
  ('2021-05-10'),
  ('2021-05-11'),
  ('2021-05-14'),
  ('2021-05-12'),
  ('2021-05-12'),
  ('2021-05-13'),
  ('2021-05-12'),
  ('2021-05-12');
```

Déjame las dudas en los comentarios para ampliar la respuesta con las explicaciones que puedas necesitar.

Comment: es mejor explicar que hace cada parte, como sabrás las explicaciones siempre se agradecen :)

Answer (score 0):

Dado que tienes que evaluar el día de la semana de cada día dentro de un rango, mejor usa una función que reciba tres parámetros: el primero sería el día de la semana a contar conforme a `dayofweek()`, es decir, base 1=Domingo. Los otros parámetros serían las fechas inicial y final del rango.

```
CREATE FUNCTION noDias( pDia INT, pIni DATE, pFin DATE ) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
   DECLARE noDias INT DEFAULT 0;
   DECLARE fecha DATE DEFAULT pIni -interval 1 day;

   IF    ( pDia is null or pDia not between 1 and 7 )
      OR ( pIni is null or pFin is null ) 
      OR ( pIni > pFin ) THEN 
      RETURN null;
   END IF;
   
   WHILE fecha < pFin DO
      SET fecha = fecha + interval 1 DAY;
      SET noDias = noDias + if( dayofweek(fecha) = pDia, 1, 0 );
   END WHILE;  
   
   RETURN noDias;
END
```

Tu consulta será:

```
SELECT edit_date, close_date
     , noDias(1,edit_date,close_date) Domingos
     , noDias(7,edit_date,close_date) Sabados
  FROM mi_table
```

Comment: Gracias por el dato, lo voy a probar.