# Insertar registros automáticos en una fecha especifica en mysql

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin

Estoy creando un pequeño de control de asistencia, cada día un encargado pasará la asistencia y todo bien hasta ahí. El problema es que a la hora de llegar al fin de semana (Sábado y Domingo) necesito que automaticamente se guarde la asistencia en la base de datos (Sea ausente o presente, según se elija la opción).
Alguien tiene alguna idea de cómo hacer esto? O si es que es posible hacerlo? Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Entonces lo que tu quieres es que cuando sea determinada fecha pase tal acción?, por ejemplo como pusiste que cuando sea sábado y domingo haga lo que tu le indiques

Comment: Siii exactamente eso! Es decir cada Sábado y Domingo de cada mes se inserte un registro automatico

Comment: Hay varias maneras de hacerlo; pero ¿cuál es el problema de la inexistencia de dichos registros? ¿es para un encargado en particular o para todos?.

Comment: lo que pasa es que necesito a fin de mes mostrar un total de asistencias para generar un pago. En este caso Sábado y Domingo se pagan haya asistido o no, por lo que en la base de datos quiero tener el registro de manera automatica

Comment: Puedes [contar el número de sábados y domingos en un rango de fechas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/461897). De lo contrario tendrías que [programar una tarea](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmysql%5D+programar+una+tarea).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

si usas Windows, Puedes crear un archivo .bat para que ejecute el archivo encargado de guardar esa información.

1. Crea un archivo en en lenguage que estes programando, el archivo debe contener el query que deseas ejecutar. Importante, los llamados que hagas a otros archivos como includes o requires deben ser con la ruta local del equipo, ej C://myProject/autoInsert.php.
2. Crea un archivo .bat, este será el ejecutable para Windows (Te recomiendo lo guardes en un lugar seguro, donde nadie mas tenga acceso desde afuera).

Ejemplo archivo .bat para PHP

```
cd "D:\myProject\"
"C:\Programdata\PHP7.0\" php.exe -f "autoInsert.php" -- onlyRunLocal=true
```

La primera linea lleva al sistema a la ruta o contenedor donde se encuentre tu archivo a ejecutar el query.

La segunda linea, lleva a la ruta donde se encuentra el compilador con el que estes trabajando, para este caso "PHP", luego le dice que ejecute el archivo autoInsert.php y que declare a onlyRunLocal = true, esa variable nos permite ejecutar nuestro archivo exclusivamente desde la tarea, nadie puede correr esa consulta a menos que sea desde el programador de tareas o ejecutando el mismo .bat

3. Crea la tarea en "Task Scheduler", realmente no es necesario describir el proceso, puesto que es muy intuitivo y existe suficiente documentación sobre ello. En la tarea programas las horas en las que deseas que se ejecute y seleccionas el archivo .bat
4. Solo para tener en cuenta, al crear la tarea, marcar la opción de "dar privilegios" y "Ejecutar si hay o no usuarios activos"

Archivo PHP

```
if(in_array('onlyRunLocal=true', $argv)){
  //Tu query aquí
}
```

Por último, recuerda dejar más especificaciones sobre tu consulta, como el lenguaje que usas, sistema operativo, versiones de tus software, ETC. Así será más fácil obtener una respuesta y por supuesto la más adecuada. Éxitos con tu proyecto!